# Attempting to purge mysql* with apt-get, unable to do so without interaction

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, apt

I'm attempting to purge MySQL completely from Ubuntu 14.04 non-interactively but can't get past a dialog that requires me to say Yes/No.

I'm running this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge -y mysql*
```

Which eventually results in this dialog:

> This operation will remove the data directory at '/var/lib/mysql' that
>   stores all the databases, tables and related meta-data. Additionally,
>   any import or export files stored at '/var/lib/mysql-files' will be
>   removed along with directory, as well as the contents of
>   /var/lib/mysql-keyring. It is highly recommended to take data backup
>   before removing the data directories. Remove data directories ? Yes |
>   No

Is there anyway I can automatically say yes? I also just tried to remove all directories before running the purge command, but this failed. This doesn't appear on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Have you tried the `--force-yes` option?

Comment: Can't test this right now, but try to use `apt-get -qq purge mysql-*`.

Comment: I have the same issue and I've tried `sudo apt-get remove --force-yes --purge -qq -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" mariadb-\*` but the message is still displayed.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` environment variable:

`sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get remove -y --purge -qq <package-name>`

`-y` to answer yes by default

`--purge` to delete all configuration files ( but seems that postsripts of dpkg will skip the removal of /var/lib/mysql folder so you will need to delete this manually.

`-qq` to tell the apt to be quiet at the highest level ( 2 ).